# Don't get result from MVC Web API with EF, 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I’m using the MVC Web API to expose my data out of my local database with Entity Framework 5. The database that I use is the Microsoft AdventureWorks2012 database.

When I expose one entity, it all works fine and I see JSON result with Fiddler. But when I add multiple entities which have relationships and when I for instance want all the sales person and the stores which belong to the sales person (return context.SalesPerson.Include(“Store”)), I get the next message in Fiddler “[Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a response for this request.”, 504 Fiddler - Receive Failure.

I don’t now if I have to transform the entity to some type or set a feature in EF, anybody got a idea/solution?

Comment: Hit the edit button and source code, expected output; in essence, what you have tried.  Without those bits it hard to give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a circular reference issue in the model. Please try the solutions in my blog http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongyes/archive/2012/09/04/loop-reference-handling-in-serializer.aspx